# Hibernate HQL JOIN - fetched association was not present

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

Having this class:

```
public class Device implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);
    private Set<Service> services = new HashSet<Service>(0);

    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "device", cascade = {     CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    @OrderBy("id")
    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

   @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "device", cascade = {     CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    @OrderBy("id")
    public Set<Service> getServices() {
        return this.services;
    }    
}
```

I want to execute this query using Hibernate Query Language with Associations and joins, the version of hibernate is the 3.2.6

```
@Override
    public int numberofProductsOrServices(String licenseNumber) {

        String queryString = "select count(*) as n from Device dev "
                + " left join fetch dev.products products "
                + " left join fetch dev.services services ";


        try {

            Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);          
            return (int)query.getSingleResult();

        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error( re);
            throw re;
        }       
    }
```

but i got this strange error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=products,role=com.domain.Device.products,tableName=T_PRODUCT,tableAlias=products1_,origin=T_DEVICE applicatio0_,colums={applicatio0_.ID ,className=eu.europa.ec.env.ecolabel.domain.Product}}] [select count(*) as n from com.domain.Device app  left join fetch app.products products  left join fetch app.services services ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to join fetch if you just want to count the entries. You need to change your query to:

```
String queryString = 
    "select count(*) as n from Device dev"
    + " left join dev.products "
    + " left join dev.services ";
```

The count doesn't really have much sense in this case either, because it will count the Cartesian product between Devices, Products and Services so I doubt it is of any good.

Comment: Perhaps a typo..i removed the "fetch" word & it worked.

Comment: No type. Are you using JPQL or native SQL? This syntax is for JPQL or HQL not for native SQL queries.

Comment: Its JPQL (JPA 2.x)..But I got the same error with "fetch" word present..I thought "I dont need to fetch since I only want to count" (as you mentioned)..then I removed the "fetch" & it worked

Comment: That's true. I modified the answer now.